# Android Widget: OnClickPendingIntent won't Work

Tags: android, android-widget

Why doesn't recieve get called when I click on Button wid??

Code:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wid, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
            Log.d("ARH","CLICKK");
        }
```

Becuase I need a button to manual refresh the widget but it seems that `Log.d("ARH","CLICKK");` only gets called when i add the Widget.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You using a PendingIntent to call an Activity but your Widget class is not an activity.

If you want to update to your widget, then you need to use getBroadcast that sends an APPWIDGET_UPDATE action.

Comment: Ok sound interesting! Do you know how I can get OnClick from a widget and update the text therefrom??

Comment: You can have the widget send your own action (not an update action) and then catch it in the onReceive function.